# Firebase Analytics in React Native iOS App sends exact same event data

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

Events that has the same data with following columns are recorded in Firebase Analytics

- `event_timestamp`
- `event_name`
- `user_pseudo_id`

Here is summarized table with Big Query

[image]

I have researched and found the following comment

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11560#issuecomment-1643873751

Is this caused by this iOS SDK bug?